# New Line in p5.js and filling text

Tags: animation, fonts, p5.js

I want my text to display as: 
"Get in 
touch"

and not as "Get in touch" in one line. Also i want the text to be filled out with blue color i am using. I am new to p5.js and happy if someone could help me out.

Here is my code:

```js
var bg;
let font
let points

function preload() {
  font = loadFont("https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f856e406d8928d0f087b08/6115974937a790256fc9abec_Telegraf-Regular.woff");
  bg = loadImage("https://i.postimg.cc/DwTMdBjn/Download.png")
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  
  points = font.textToPoints('GET IN TOUCH', window.innerWidth/7.5, window.innerHeight/2, windowWidth/9.5, {
    sampleFactor: 1,
    simplyThreshold: 1,
  })
}

function draw() {
  background(bg)
  
  fill('#000099')
  noStroke()

  points.forEach(point => {
    const distance = createVector(point.x - mouseX, point.y - mouseY)
    const distortion = distance.mult(60 / distance.mag())

    circle(point.x + distortion.x, point.y + distortion.y, 1.5)
  })
}
window.onresize = function() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.size(w,h);
  width = w;
  height = h;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
<script src="sketch.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for making the letters closed. "O" has a problem with it since it can't be drawn as one path, but it's minimal when you don't hover over it.
You can run two separate strings and offset their y to make a new line.

```js
    var bg;
let font
let points = [];

let str = "GET IN TOUCH"

function preload() {
  font = loadFont("https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f856e406d8928d0f087b08/6115974937a790256fc9abec_Telegraf-Regular.woff");
  bg = loadImage("https://i.postimg.cc/DwTMdBjn/Download.png")
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  
  
  
  for(i = 0; i < str.length; i ++){
  points[i] = font.textToPoints(str[i], window.innerWidth/7.5 + i * 50, window.innerHeight/2, windowWidth/9.5, {
    sampleFactor: 1,
    simplyThreshold: 1,
  })
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(bg)
  
  fill('#000099')
  noStroke()

  for(i = 0; i < points.length; i ++){
    beginShape();
  points[i].forEach(point => {
    const distance = createVector(point.x - mouseX, point.y - mouseY)
    const distortion = distance.mult(60 / distance.mag())

    curveVertex(point.x + distortion.x, point.y + distortion.y)
  })
    endShape();
  }
}
window.onresize = function() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  //canvas.size(w,h);
  width = w;
  height = h;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
<script src="sketch.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!